# How can I rename an existentially quantified variable in a hypothesis?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Is there an easy way to rename an existential variable in a hypothesis?
Sometimes the variable names are confusing, because the same names  are reused in unrelated hypotheses.

For example, I want to change `H1 : exists p : nat, n0 = p * 2` to `H1 : exists pminus1 : nat, n0 = pminus1 * 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that does it:

```
match goal with
  an_h : @ex _ (?f) |- _ =>
  let new_f := eval lazy beta in (fun pminus_one => f pminus_one) in
  assert (my_h : @ex _ new_f) by exact an_h; clear an_h
end.
```